# Adobe analytics Can we do push notification in a web app with JS implementation and no sdk

Tags: push-notification, adobe, adobe-analytics

this mobile app is a web based SPA that is done through adobe Launch as regular javascript code throughout the entire app, Adobe doc says to do push notifiction using SDK. However we havent used SDK here how would we do push notification in this stance?

Comment: this web app is loaded through a mobile app, or it is a progressive web app for mobile?

Comment: @rob it is loaded through a mobile app